# Capturing a text/title on the webpage using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver, selenium-rc, capture

I am attempting to capture a text (title for different panels on a webpage) and verify the text content. I tried using the xpath to capture the text, but surprisingly on WebDriver, it fails. The same xpath seems to work perfectly fine with the Selenium RC. I wonder why WebDriver does not seem to recognize the xpath while RC does!! The code I have tried is given below:

```
assertEquals("Identification requests", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[8]")).getText());
```

I also tried the complete xpath:

```
assertEquals("Identification requests", driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/kibana-panel/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/span[8]")).getText());
```

I attempted using the class variable too, but none of these seem to be returning any results. All the attempts fail with an error that the element was not found.

The html code for that portion is as shown below:

```
<span class="panel-text panel-title ng-binding">Identification requests</span>
```

The HTML code surrounding the span portion mentioned above is as shown below:

```
<div class="row-fluid panel-extra">
<div class="panel-extra-container">
<span class="extra row-button" ng-show="panel.editable != false && panel.removable != false">
<span class="extra row-button" ng-hide="panel.draggable == false">
<span class="row-button extra" ng-show="panel.editable != false">
<span class="row-button extra ng-scope" ng-show="task.show" ng-repeat="task in panelMeta.modals">
<span class="row-button extra ng-scope" ng-show="task.show" ng-repeat="task in panelMeta.modals">
<span class="row-button extra ng-scope" ng-show="task.show" ng-repeat="task in panelMeta.modals">
<span class="row-button extra" ng-show="panelMeta.loading == true" style="display: none;">
<span class="panel-text panel-title ng-binding">Identification requests</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have doubts about why the xpath that works for RC wouldn't work for WebDriver. And how I would be able to capture the text?

Comment: could you post the HTML that surrounds the `<span>` please?

Comment: If there is any chance that your `span` is generated dynamically, you might want to try pausing your code for a few seconds just before the `assertEquals` call, and see if this solves the issue. If this pause solves the issue, then you want to use an explicit wait to wait for the element to be present.

Comment: @sircapsalot I have added the HTML surrounding the span into the details above.

Comment: @Louis: Thanks for the suggestion. I did add a wait but that did not help. Also, while attempting to debug too I do provide sufficient time before I move to the next step of capturing the text but it always fails with the error noelementfound. :(
Also, the span is not generated dynamically. They represent the title for the graphs that are being displayed in a certain portion of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following (use css selector):

```
String spanCssSelector ="span.panel-text.panel-title.ng-binding";
WebElement spanItem=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(spanCssSelector));
String textObtained= spanItem.getText().trim();
assertEquals(textObtained,"Identification requests");
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. It still reports that the element was unable to be located.

    org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"span.panel-text.panel-title.ng-binding"}
Command duration or timeout: 30.17 seconds

Answer (score 0):

You can use assert

```
assertEquals("Identification requests", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[starts-with(@class, 'panel-text')]")).getText());
```

Or

```
assertEquals("Identification requests", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='panel-text panel-title ng-binding']")).getText());
```

Or just findElement via text() function of Xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[starts-with(@class, 'panel-text')][text()='Identification requests']));
```

Or via full class attribute value:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='panel-text panel-title ng-binding'][text()='Identification requests']));
```